# Good Gui editors for win C programming

Tags: c, windows, user-interface

I am trying to get back to C programming in windows.

I normally use codeblocks for the code and for the gui I used Resource Editor from radasm, but it seems it's no longer available.

Anyone know of a simple program that will let me create dialogs, edit existing resource files and such easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Qt Creator](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/developer-tools) is capable of doing all those things, if you choose to use Qt for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Borland C++

Dev -C++

Eclipse CDT

LCC-Win

V IDE

WideStudio

Ultimate++

wx-Devcpp

wxWidgets

Comment: I just wanted a GUI Editor not an IDE. Dev-C++ does not offer a GUI editor.

Like I said in the question. I just wanted something simple as Resource Editor from radasm

Answer (score 0):

You could try GTK [gtk.org](http://gtk.org).

You can find the tutorials [here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/)

[Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) is the preferred RAD tool for resource editting

Answer (score -2):

A window platform, with UI editor and can automatically generate form classes, control variables, message mapping like MFC UI library
SourceCode：https://github.com/miaomiaoyule/DUIThink

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35751487)